# How to call data form an API endpoint using a HTML text form box?

Tags: php, html, api

I am trying to assist a app developer with connecting to the Audiomack database via API consumer_key & consumer secret

[  Key = *X*X*X*X*X*   |   Secret = *X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X  ]

The goal is to request Artist data via a FORM POST text field box, and have the PHP script connect to Audiomack via API  to GET the data requested in the FORM POST text field box, and have it return the search results in JSON format. Then once this is established the secondary goal is to have the returning JSON results be dumped into our local MYSQL database tables as users search for artist and music.

I have installed the PECL extension package, and my client has purchased and installed Comodo SSL cert for HTTPS protocol on the Bluehost server as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html/; charset=utf-8" />
<title>contrabandhiphop | search results</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="home.php"><h1>contrabandhiphop search results</h1></a>

<!-- Search Form Box -->

<form method="get" action="search4.php">
    <input type="text" name="k" size="50" value="<?php echo $_GET['k'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>

<!-- API Connection -->

<?php
 $k = $_GET['k'];
 $terms = explode("  ", $k);{
 }
 
 $api_base = 'https://www.audiomack.com/v1/artist';
 $conskey  = '*X*X*X*X*X';
 $conssec  = '*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*X*';

 try {
  $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
  $oauth->fetch($api_base . '$k');
  print json_encode($json); 
 }
 catch(OAuthException $E) {
  echo json_encode($E);
 }
 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you point to the API documentation because that looks a little odd

Comment: Here it is:  https://www.audiomack.com/data-api/docs#example-code-php